# products are still in cart after checkout- woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

is there any option in woocommerce to remove products from cart after checkout ? at the beginning of the project , it was working fine but now the products remained in the cart . any ideas / suggestions please ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: That isn't default behavior, so I presume the trouble is coming from one of your plugins and/or your own custom code.

Comment: As helgatheviking stated, when someone goes wrong with your checkout process, the cart will not be emptied.  Depending on which payment gateway you're using, try turning on logging and place a test purchase and see what the log says.  That would be a good starting point to troubleshoot.  Also try the default PayPal Standard and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

See also:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_received_empty_cart_action', 10, 1 );
function order_received_empty_cart_action( $order_id ){
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

https://theme.co/forum/t/woo-commerce-cart-not-clearing-after-purchase/41552/5